# How do you program a translator with lists in prolog?

Tags: prolog, machine-translation

What I want to do is a translator in Prolog. I've done something like this to translate one word:

```
traducir(X,Y) :- traduccion( X, Y ).
traduccion(gato,cat).
```

And when you ask Prolog `traducir(X,cat)` , it answers `X=gato`
What I want to do is a translator where you ask something like `traducir(X,[Hola,mi,nombre,es,Juan]).` and Prolog's  answer should be `X=[Hello,my,name,is,John]`.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Prolog: converting atom to new atom](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6002279/prolog-converting-atom-to-new-atom)

Comment: see also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7542406

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is another one :

```
traducir(Xs, Ys) :- maplist(traduccion, Xs, Ys).
```

Comment: The cut is a red one.  And you can remove `length/2` and `!` from the program. The `maplist/3` goal is all that is needed.

Comment: You sir are as usual totally right :) I do not know why I inserted those lengths predicate when taking another look at it. Anyway, corrected! Thanks for pointing that out.

Answer (score 4):

```
traducir([],[]).
traducir([Hin|Tin], [Hout|Tout]) :-
    traduccion(Hin, Hout),
    traducir(Tin,Tout).
```

Comment: I think you meant `traducir([Hin|Tin], [Hout|Tout]) :- traduccion(Hin, Hout), traducir(Tin,Tout).` in your second clause

Comment: could you please post an example about how to try  this?

Comment: @user1073782 traducir(X,[hola,mi,nombre,es,juan]). Make sure you have the underlying facts for traduccion(hola,hello). etc. Remember, upper case makes a would-be atom a variable, so Juan needs to become juan.

Comment: or Juan needs to become 'Juan' btw.

Answer (score 0):

Also add a catchall predicate

```
     tranduccion(X,X)
```

at the bottom of your logicbase, if you want to include names of people, that are not translated.

Answer (score 0):

To translate several languages into several others, you can write a predicate like this one:

```
translate(Lang1,X,Lang2,Y) :-
    Translations = [
        [
            [spanish,perro],
            [english,dog],
            [french,chien],
            [german,hund],
            [italian,cane]
        ],
        [
            [french,chat],
            [spanish,gato],
            [english,cat]
        ]
        %You can add more lists of translations here if necessary.
    ],
    member(Translation,Translations),
    member([Lang1,X],Translation),
    member([Lang2,Y],Translation).
```

Now you can define the `traducir` predicate like this:

```
traducir(X,Y) :- translate(spanish,X,english,Y).
```